# Format String .NET C#

Tags: .net, string

How do you do the following format on this string

String
contact_informaton_monday

Convert to:
ContactInformationMonday

Basically do the following things:

1. Make the first character upper case (I don't have a problem with
   that)
2. Replace each _(next_letter) by removing the underscore and just
   upper casing the next letter.

Thank you

Comment: Always show us your work and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
var str = "contact_informaton_monday";
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var s in str.Split("_"))
{
    sb.Append(s.Substring(0, 1).toUpper());
    sb.Append(s.Substring(1));
}
str = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var textInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
var input = "contact_informaton_monday";
var output = string.Concat(
    input.Split('_').Select(i => textInfo.ToTitleCase(i))
);
```

Comment: For the example this will work, but `ToTitleCase` will not capitalise the first letter of words such as and ect.

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko, [generally, title casing converts the first character of a word to uppercase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx) (Remarks section)

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string by the "_" character. After that it's all downhill.

Answer (score 1):

Split string:

```
var s = "contact_informaton_monday";
var final = "";
foreach (var split in s.Split('_'))
    final += split.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + split.Substring(1);
```

Or regular expressions:

```
var s = "contact_informaton_monday";
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"(\b|_)[a-z]", e => e.Value.ToUpper());
s = Regex.Replace(s, "_", "");
// s=ContactInformationMonday
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str.Split("_").ForEach(x => char.ToUpper(x[0]) + x.Substring(1)).ToArray().Join();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string outputWord = "";
string word = "contact_informaton_monday";
foreach (var s in word.Split('_'))
{
     outputWord += s.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + s.Substring(1);
}
```